# How to render images in custom extbase extension using Typo3 7.5 Image cropping?

Tags: typo3, extbase

does anybody know how to implement the image cropping for a custom extbase extension ? I know how to display the image form field for the backend part, but not the rendering in the extension template. 
I know that the fluid_styled_content sysext uses the `TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\GalleryProcessor` assigned to the textmedia content element via typoscript in the extension setup.txt, but I don't know how to implement it in a custom extension.

Can anybody help me here ?
thanks,Lukas

Comment: do you have "image" field in your extension with FAL inline TCA configuration?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy I found out. The viewhelper f:media renders the image correctly, taking into account the image settings in the image field.

```
<f:media
    file="{image}"
    width="{column.dimensions.width}"
    height="{column.dimensions.height}"
    alt="{column.media.alternative}"
    title="{column.media.title}"
    />
```

Answer (score -1):

Fluid template example:

```
<f:image
    image="{image}"
    alt="{image.originalResource.title}"
    width="460c"
    height="460c"
    treatIdAsReference="TRUE"
/>
```

Value {image} must contain FAL image object.

Image is cropped by attributes width="460c" and height="460c".

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's the way to render a normal image. But,  new Typo3 7 has the possibility define the frame of the image and crop it as an editor. But... I found the solution myself, it's similar to yours.

Comment: This solution does not take the crop funktionality of typo3 7.6 into account. f:media do so.